# Do we connect the ground rails on both sides of a SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, grounding

Is there any reason for, or not for, connecting the ground of the high voltage DC line with the ground of the low voltage DC rail(s) across the transformer in a switch mode power supply (SMPS)?

I've seen that it is common for a single low charge capacitor to be placed across the transformer of a SMPS to connect the two ground planes (presumably for noise cancelation), but I'm not sure why you wouldn't connect the grounds like you would in most other circuits.

Comment: Google "galvanic isolation", "y-capacitor" and "electrocution by non-isolated power supply" and report back.

Comment: @Hazza, please post the datasheet for the power supply?  What are you using the power supply for?  What are you powering with it?  What's the end application?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I'm talking more about a generic case (If applicable here?)

Comment: Are you asking about a shock-hazard issue or just an isolated vs. grounded power supply issue?

Comment: If your incoming power consists of a line and neutral (or two lines), you do not have a ground on the primary side - most double insulated devices. Connecting a user-accessible output ground to the incoming mains (either line or neutral) is a very very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Regulatory agencies require galvanic isolation between the primary-side and any user-accessible voltages; this is provided by the transformer, maintaining creepages/clearances between primary and secondaries, etc.

Capacitor connection between primary return (the rectified low-side) and output return is done for noise attentuation, as you have observed. This is often done with two agency-recognized capacitors in series, so that if there is a single failure you still have a recognized component providing some measure of safety.

Often the low-side of the user-accessible output is tied to earth/chassis, again for noise reasons (and to have a solid reference point). Tying the bulk DC low-side to the output in this circumstance also ties it to earth, which (if your AC distribution is using a neutral) means that you're shorting your bridge out. This is a bad thing.

(Inexperienced or sleepy people sometimes inadvertently simulate this scenario by touching an earthed oscilloscope probe return to the bulk DC low side. Often the scope protects the power supply fuse by blowing itself to smithereens first, or turning the scope lead into a toaster element by glowing red, but YMMV)

Comment: Not a bad answer but wouldn't you say it is more for your own safety than it is for the regulatory agencies sake. Those are just put in the world to protect the rest of us from people who don't know why not to connect the primary to the secondary ground ;P

Comment: This makes some sense, but is this for a linear power supply or for switch mode? or both?

Comment: Any mains-powered supply will require galvanic isolation if the output is user-accessible. Linear or switcher, it doesn't matter.